# bootstrap 3 collapsing navbar icon-bar not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

New to bootstrap and trying to build an navbar that when it collapses the menu items disappear and it shows the three icon bars, which when clicked shows the menus dropped down.  The code works up to the point when you click on the icon bars, but when its clicked the menu items are not shown.  Any suggestions.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-      target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Text Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">about</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">tutorias</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">contact</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is whitespace in your `data-      target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"` HTML.. If you remove this it should work fine:

http://bootply.com/88198

Also, `navbar-ex1-collapse` is used for the Bootstrap docs since there are several example navbars. You can set the `data-target=".navbar-collapse"` and it will also work.